# Trying to map elements from object of nested subarrays to a cell in an HTML table, unsure how to reach deepest sub arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have a React/TypeScript component I'm building that features an HTML table for contact details.

I'm trying to map the API response to cells in the table and dynamically populate rows for each contact and their details. There are two arrays for *phone numbers* and *addresses* that are nested deep within the object and I can't figure out how to iterate over them along with the rest of the data all in one go.

I initially tried nested for loops but I hit a wall when I got to those two elements because of their position in the data object.

I then tried to use *.map()* in the middle of the *for* loops, but I hit a TypeScript error stating the element I'm trying to map over could possibly be null.

I thought about iterating over phone number and address arrays separately and then inserting them into the appropriate cells per contact but I can't figure out how to do when I'm using separate for loops to populate the other cells.

Expected Output:

```
Name | Member | Telephone | Email | Addresses

Ben B| Friend | 610-535-1234 | ben@gmail.com | 123 Fiction Drive,Denver
                215-674-6789                   234 Dreary Ln,Seattle 

Alice | Family| 267-333-1234 | ally@aim.com  | 437 Chance St, Pitts.
```

I made a CodeSandbox and dropped the current component and example data structure below. For the CodeSandbox it currently loads but as soon as you uncomment these lines you'll see the error

```
<td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].phoneNumbers}</td>

<td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].addresses}</td>
```

[image: Edit crazy-edison-6l6ue]

```
Current Component
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Contacts } from "./contact-types";

type Props = {
  contacts: Contacts;
};

export const ContactsGrid = (props: Props) => {

  const { contacts } = props;

  const rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.contactGroups.length; i++) {
    rows.push(
      <tr>
        <td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contactGroup}</td>
      </tr>
    );
    for (let j = 0; j < contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts.length; j++) {
      rows.push(
        <tr>
          <td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].fullName}</td>
          <td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].member}</td>
          {/* <td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].phoneNumbers}</td> */}
          <td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].email}</td>
          {/* <td>{contacts.contactGroups[i].contacts[j].addresses}</td> */}
        </tr>
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Member Type</td>
          <td>Telephone</td>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>Address</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

```
Current Data Structure
```

```
export default {
  count: 1,
  contactGroups: [
    {
      contactGroup: "Family",
      count: 1,
      contacts: [
        {
          member: "Uncle",
          fullName: "BENJAMIN BILLIARDS",
          lastName: "BILLIARDS",
          firstName: "BENJAMIN",
          email: "shark@billiards.com",
          phoneNumbers: [
            {
              telephoneNumber: "123-456-7899",
              type: "mobile"
            },
            {
              telephoneNumber: "610-555-7625",
              type: "work"
            }
          ],
          addresses: [
            {
              addressLine1: "123 FAMILY ST",
              addressLine2: "APT 1208",
              city: "ATLANTA",
              state: "GEORGIA",
              zipCode: "12345"
            },
            {
              addressLine1: "456 WORKING BLVD",
              addressLine2: "",
              city: "ATLANTA",
              state: "GEORGIA",
              zipCode: "12345"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      contactGroup: "Friends",
      count: 1,
      contacts: [
        {
          member: "School Friend",
          fullName: "HANS ZIMMER",
          lastName: "ZIMMER",
          firstName: "HANS",
          email: "hans@pirates.com",
          phoneNumbers: [
            {
              telephoneNumber: "267-455-1234",
              type: "mobile"
            }
          ],
          addresses: [
            {
              addressLine1: "789 FRIEND ST",
              addressLine2: "",
              city: "SAN DIEGO",
              state: "CALIFORNIA",
              zipCode: "67890"
            },
            {
              addressLine1: "234 CANARY ST",
              addressLine2: "",
              city: "SEATTLE",
              state: "WASHINGTON",
              zipCode: "67890"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: It is not clear how the resulting rows are supposed to look because you're using a property `contactGroup` for which there is not header.

Comment: The contactGroup section will actually display beneath the header labels and will display the contacts for each contactGroup underneath their associated group title. If you look at the first section of the for loop that's where the contactGroup name is being populated first and then for each contact in the group, they are mapped beneath that

Comment: Adding an example output will probably help.

Comment: Just added the expected output at the top

Comment: Do you want to have all the phone numbers / addresses of the same contact in the same cell (same `<td>` element) ?

Comment: If that is the case, here is an example of how you could make it work: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-goodall-kkjhq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested `map`:

```
const rows = contacts.contactGroups.map(group => <tr>
  <td>{group.contactGroup}</td>
  <td>
  <table>
    {group.contacts.map(contact => <tr>
      <td>{contact.fullName}
    </tr>}
  </table>
  </td>
</tr>;
```

Comment: Hmm I'm trying to map the phone numbers array and it's saying ```cannot map property of undefined```